# How to swap array values in PostgreSQL.?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

How to swap array values in PostgreSQL. For example i have a table that has a column whose data type is `bigint[]`. It has following value in it.

value: `{111, 222, 333}`
My desired output is `{333, 111, 222}`

i can not find any built in function to achieve other than array_replace.

Comment: Do you always have only 3 items in the array or is the count dynamic?

Comment: It's dynamic array.

Comment: If it's dynamic, what are the rules for "swapping"?

Answer (score 1):

You can access the values by index, as follows:

```
postgres=# create table intarray ( aaa int8[] ) ;
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# insert into intarray values ( ARRAY [ 111, 222, 333 ]  ) ;
INSERT 0 1
postgres=# select * from intarray;
      aaa      
---------------
 {111,222,333}
(1 row)

postgres=# select aaa[3],aaa[2],aaa[1] from intarray;
 aaa | aaa | aaa 
-----+-----+-----
 333 | 222 | 111
(1 row)

postgres=# select ARRAY[aaa[3],aaa[1],aaa[2]] from intarray;
     array     
---------------
 {333,111,222}
(1 row)

postgres=#
```

[Reading the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html) may help you.

Comment: It's dynamic array.